# Where can I find a Buddist Monastery that practice hard training?

Tags: monastery

I wish to master my mind, one reason is I'm so mentally weak. Like anything you want to master you have to work at it. Drill it into you. But practicing on my own hasn't work. I need a far away place that will force me to master meditation. If I get off track they will make sure I get back on track. Where is a monastery like this where I a foreigner can join for a year?

Comment: Some possible useful accounts: [Q&A Proper way to ask a teacher to become their student](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8135.msg12395.html#msg12395)

Answer (score 2):

Following are some pointers:

1. https://www.dhamma.org/en/index
2. http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/global/index.html
3. http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/
4. https://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/
5. https://forestsangha.org/

With regard to the 1st 2 links, there are 10-day courses. In the case of the 1st link, you can progress to longer courses up to 60 days. 3rd link lists many other monasteries and centres which some may allow you to stay up to a year. 4th links gives meditation centres in the Pa Auk tradition which is the best if you are looking to master Jhana. 5th link gives monasteries in the Thai Forrest tradition.

Comment: Thank you my friend truly. Also thanks for giving me options

Answer (score 1):

Any meditation monastery has sufficient disciple for training. There is no need to think as extreme as you are. [Wat Pah Nanachat](http://www.watpahnanachat.org/) in Thailand or any [branch monastery](https://forestsangha.org/community/monasteries).

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to take a look at mahamevnawa. They have many branches world wide. Below is link to help locate a branch.

- [Worldwide Mahamevnawa Branches](https://mahamevnawabm.org/worldwide-mahamevnawa-branches/)

[image]

If you in the east coast of USA, I may suggest [Mahamevnawa Buddhist Meditation Center of New Jersey](https://mahamevnawanj.org/)

Answer (score -1):

A lame horse if whipped will not run faster. Based on your approach it may take you a long time to form discipline. In fact what does it have to do with a monastery? If you're having trouble concentrating that could be adult adhd I recommend: 3 months of a basic counseling and/ or medication might help you prepare for religious approach. It's cheaper that a flight and you'll introspective work towards the same goal. In fact you can do both together. You reached a point where your aware of a limitation. This is valuable so don't think nothing isn't progress. As eager student will you not listen to this reasonable advice?

Comment: Its not so much I can't focus. I wish to mastet jhana meditation and even held access concentration. Its I cant be reasonable to put the work in it take to master this meditation. I will always find a reason to not do it or quit. But I see your point. I just need a place I have to worry about nothing else other then meditation

Comment: Find somewhere uncomfortable and mostly private. A bedroom is no good and a garden isn't either. You'll be caught in the view.

Comment: I tried that.. So much I JUST came back from a trip from hawaii with the aim of mediation and didn't even mediate for 3p mintues I was there for a week.. I can't forcr myself I will find away out

Comment: Hawaii is somewhere nice. Some students can't meditate. One of my stubborn ones is like this. Walking medication works better. The idea is work while working, sleep while sleeping and bathe while bathing. You sound like you could also use a koan. Would you like one?

Comment: `In fact what does it have to do with a monastery?` Don't humans learn by copying (emulating) each other? Isn't easier to do what others are doing, when and because they're doing it?

Comment: Chrisw you have a valuable point. There's issues with mimicking. One is that someone can appear to have the point and might bring forth some good doing so but unless that individual knows it well enough there isn't going to be the bridge of understanding. It's like pointing at the moon and understanding the fingers. If they aren't catching the point for the point- There's the gap. A way of looking at meditation and enlighten is to shed your artificial reality. How do you learn what you don't? This is good for knowledge. It isn't the same candle as wisdom. teachers teach. A master doesn't.

Comment: But before the goal (i.e. "understanding"), let's just look at behaviour (dependent condition). The OP wants to regulate his behaviour/practice. I think that non-independent humans are (from an earliest age) highly motivated by society. Perception of society's approval etc is a very strong incentive, I imagine -- "Either you meditate when others do, or you'll have to leave the monastery!" Given that social/peer pressure is so strong, in-bred, I think people use/harness that human tendency, and willingly, in all fields of endeavour: athletes with athletes, students with students. Isn't that so?

Comment: In Zen there are mechanisms to support and deny this. The relationship of master and student is an individual one. Having a sense of belonging does not one make for a good student. In general teaching this is a fairly usual bridge. It does create limitations of a student. Temples are designed for many different individuals. The idea is one does not disturb others. My roshi said it like this: "one eye, one dimension. Two eyes two dimensions, four eyes four dimensions and so on." The eyes provide some insight. Who gets the gold? Does this person run with others?